# Jquery Input rules is not working in XMLHttpRequest

Tags: php, html, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have rules in the input box, I created them with jQuery, I called the input box using XMLHttpRequest. After I called it using XMLHttpRequest, all the rules I had created failed.

But I've tried not using XMLHttpRequest, all the rules I made worked perfectly. why is that?

I want the rules in my input boxes to all work, even if I call them with XMLHttpRequest.

this is my simple code in the first file (z1.php):

```
 <?php
    include('z1ajax.php');
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>SIGN UP</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/to/img/bqicon.png"/>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-v2CJ7UaYy4JwqLDIrZUI/4hqeoQieOmAZNXBeQyjo21dadnwR+8ZaIJVT8EE2iyI61OV8e6M8PP2/4hpQINQ/g==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <style>
        body{
            background-color:black;
        }
    </style>
    <script>
        window.onload=function(){
            var signup = document.getElementById("signup");
            var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xhr.open("POST", "/to/z1ajax.php", true);
            xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            xhr.onreadystatechange=function(){
                if(xhr.readyState==4 && xhr.status==200){
                    signup.innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
                }
            }
            var v="onload=yes";
            xhr.send(v);
        }
        
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $('#email').on('keyup',function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var value = $this.val();
                $this.val(value.replace(/\s+/g,'')); //NO SPACE
                $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase()); //LOWERCASE
            });
            $('#username').bind('keyup keypress blur', function(){ 
                $(this).val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/[^a-z]/,''); //LOWERCASE, NO SPACE, LETTER ONLY
                });
            });
            $('#namapang').bind('keyup keypress blur', function(){ 
                $(this).val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/[^a-z]/,''); //LOWERCASE, NO SPACE, LETTER ONLY
                });
            });
            $('#pwd').on('keyup',function(){
                var $this = $(this);
                var value = $this.val();
                $this.val(value.replace(/\s+/g,'')); //NO SPACE
            });
            $('#city').bind('keyup keypress blur', function(){ 
                $(this).val(function(i, val) {
                    return val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/,''); //LETTER ONLY WITH SPACE
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id='signup'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

This is my simple code in the second file (z1ajax.php):

```
<?php
    $onload=isset($_REQUEST['onload'])?$_REQUEST['onload']:null;
    if($onload=='yes'){
?>
        <br>
        <div class='container'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-md-4'></div>
                <div class='col-md-4'>
                    <center>
                        <font size='4'><strong><font color='white'>SIGN UP</font></strong></font><br>
                    </center>
                    <br>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span></span>
                        <input type='email' id='email' class='form-control' placeholder='Email aktif'>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin'></span></span>
                        <input type='text' id='username' class='form-control' placeholder='username'>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card'></span></span>
                        <input type='text' id='namapang' class='form-control' placeholder='nama panggilan'>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card'></span></span>
                        <input type='password' id='pwd' class='form-control' placeholder='password untuk login'>
                        <span class='input-group-addon'><span id='eye' class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close' onclick="seppwd('pwd')"></span></span>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                    <div class='input-group'>
                        <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span></span>
                        <input type='text' id='city' class='form-control' placeholder='kota'>
                    </div>
                    <br>
                </div>
                <div class='col-md-4'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php
    }
?>
```

Comment: I've tried using your advice, but it still doesn't work

Comment: @Death-is-the-real-truth That is incorrect delegation

Comment: You are making a POST request to `z1ajax.php` at page load but the content that you load as a result of that ajax request does not exist in the DOM when you call `$(document).ready(function(){`

Comment: As you are using PHP you could simply get PHP to load in the FORM rather than (mis)using an AJAX request to fetch the same HTML content.. at least that way the jQuery event handlers would register correctly

Comment: @mplungjan I don't think so. `$(#signup)` is already present on the page  in which  HTML got pasted after the ajax call.

Comment: @Death-is-the-real-truth Yes. The correct delegation is `$('#signup').on('input', 'selector', function ...`

Comment: Agree with @ProfessorAbronsius on the point that you can directly use the form rather than loading it via ajax as its a sing-up form not and edit form of any record coming in a tabular list.

Comment: After seeing the suggestions from all of you. Ok then, I give up, I don't use XMLHttpsRequest anymore for the form. Thank you guys for the suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you MUST ajax the form

1. Give the fields one or more classes lowerCase, noSpace or letterOnly
2. Delegate using .on from the container

```js
$(function() {
  $('#signup')
    .on('input', '.lowerCase.noSpace', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var value = $this.val();
      $this.val(value.replace(/\s+/g, '')); //NO SPACE
      $(this).val($(this).val().toLowerCase()); //LOWERCASE
    })
    .on('input blur', '.lowerCase.noSpace', function() {
      $(this).val(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(/[^a-z]/, ''); //LOWERCASE, NO SPACE, LETTER ONLY
      });
    })
    .on('input blur', '.noSpace', function() {
      var $this = $(this);
      var value = $this.val();
      $this.val(value.replace(/\s+/g, '')); //NO SPACE
    })
    .on('input blur', '.letterOnly', function() {
      $(this).val(function(i, val) {
        return val.replace(/[^a-zA-Z ]/, ''); //LETTER ONLY WITH SPACE
      });
    });
  $.post('/to/z1ajax.php', (data) => $signup.html(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='signup'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
      <div class='col-md-4'></div>
      <div class='col-md-4'>
        <center>
          <font size='4'><strong><font color='white'>SIGN UP</font></strong></font><br>
        </center>
        <br>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-envelope'></span></span>
          <input type='email' id='email' class='form-control lowerCase noSpace' placeholder='Email aktif'>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-pushpin'></span></span>
          <input type='text' id='username' class='form-control lowerCase noSpace' placeholder='username'>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card'></span></span>
          <input type='text' id='namapang' class='form-control lowerCase noSpace letterOnly' placeholder='nama panggilan'>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-credit-card'></span></span>
          <input type='password' id='pwd' class='form-control noSpace' placeholder='password untuk login'>
          <span class='input-group-addon'><span id='eye' class='glyphicon glyphicon-eye-close' onclick="seppwd('pwd')"></span></span>
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class='input-group'>
          <span class='input-group-addon'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-home'></span></span>
          <input type='text' id='city' class='form-control letterOnly' placeholder='kota'>
        </div>
        <br>
      </div>
    </div>
```

But as already pointed out, you can just include it using php

as it seems you are already

Comment: I have copied and pasted your code, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: You need to change the classes on the fields to reuse the scripts

Comment: OMG it works. You are born to this mplugjan. Thanks a lot.